# length of hypotenuse where only part know

Tags: trigonometry

> [image: IGCSE 2019 question]

The above links to a question in the 2019 IGCSE maths 0580 specimen paper.

I know the answer is $75$, and have been able to figure this out logically, namely $$\frac{35}{7} \times 8 = 40 + 35 = 75.$$ However the answer paper seems to suggest this can be answered using "correct trig or Pythagoras’ method
leading to value rounding to 40.0". I am a bit stumped by this as I don't see how...any help appreciated.

Comment: Possibly they mean $\ell - 35 = 40$?

Comment: Please don't write $\frac{35}{7} \times 8 = 40 + 35$. I know it's tempting, but $\frac{35}7\times 8$ is _not_ the same as $40 + 35=75$. The equals sign doesn't mean "Now compute" the way it seems to do on some calculators. It means "Whatever is on the left side is exactly the same as whatever is on the right side".

Answer (score 1):

Obviously either the question meant to ask about just the length of the dotted line segment, or the person supplying the answer *thought* the question was about that segment rather than the whole line labeled $\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be solved using similarity of triangles 
The triangle having base of 8 cm is similar to the triangle having base of 15 cm . The hypotenuse of the smaller triangle will be 
$l-35$  and and that of the larger triangle would be $l$ thus 
by using properties of similarity of triangles we get 
$$ \frac{8}{l-35} = \frac{15}{l} $$
$$ 8l = 15l -525 $$
$$7l =525 $$
$$ l=75 $$

Comment: It would be great if you show how you arrived at 40

Comment: Typographical error:  In your second sentence, you meant to write $l - 35$.